# I have Css Issue Regarding to Fix My Page Footer

Tags: html, css, less

I know this question may seem repeated question, but i grant that i look several link already, and tried their resolve but it didn't worked.

what i have is a page, which contain a little border around it, several div inside each other, and then i split my page in 3 rows of div, one should be footer, and other two are header and container,

nothing in my page is sticky, all of them should scroll together,...

with several last link i checked, my new Style (LESS/CSS) file become like this

```
@main-layout-padding-top-bottom:10px;

* {
    font-family: tahoma;
}

html, body {
    direction: rtl;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: right;
}

.layout-main-holder {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: @main-layout-padding-top-bottom;
    padding-top: @main-layout-padding-top-bottom;
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url('Images/stardust.png');

    >.layout-main-inner {
        width: 900px;
        background-image: url('Images/wet_snow.png');
        margin:  0 auto;
        min-height: 100%;
        height:100%;
        padding-top: 10px;
        -ms-border-radius: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        border-radius: 10px;

        -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px;
        -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px;
        -ms-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px;
    }

}

.layout-header {
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.layout-content {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: right;
    display: block;
    position:relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height:auto !important; /* for all browsers */
    height:100%; /* for IE6 which treats this as min-height*/
    min-height:100%; /* for all browsers */
}

@footerHeight:20px;

.layout-footer {
    position:absolute;
    //width:100%;
    bottom:@main-layout-padding-top-bottom; /* stick to bottom */
    height:@footerHeight;

    /*padding: 10px;*/

    //left: 0;
    width: 900px;

    >div
    {
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: bold;
        direction: ltr;
        font-family: 'Times new roman';

        padding-left: 20px;
        width: 100%;
        margin: auto;
        text-align: left;
    }
}
```

but still there are issues, like , when the content grows it overflow from my page, instead of increase the container height.
and the other issue made me worry all the time, is that if i scroll a bit, i see a white box below my page, i don't know where it come from, when i check layout in firefox, even my HTML tag doesn't fill the whole page, so the white box stay there :|

my html layout is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

        <link href="~/Components/bootstrap-3.1.1-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


        <link href="~/Content/layout.less" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="~/Content/style.less" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>

        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

        <script src="~/Components/bootstrap-3.1.1-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="layout-main-holder">
            <div class="layout-main-inner">
                <div class="layout-header">
                    اشتراک لینک
                </div>
                <div class="layout-content">
                    @RenderBody()
                </div>
                <div class="layout-footer">
                    <div>
                        &copy; 2014 Faridad Company
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is just a case of trial and error. First you have multiple lines for "height" in your CSS. Remove them one by one and see what happens (height: 100%, height: auto, min-height: 100% -- really?). Absolute positioning can be a problem, particularly with overall layout - change it.

Comment: I removed them one bye one all have same effect on big content,  the content section is out of layout... And for all if content is inside every thing is good, also I usr min height with absolute  100% height because most of time browser don't set height to minimum height itself

Comment: That is quite a lot of code. A fiddle would be useful, so we can see it in action...

Comment: It's base layout only codes and it's less if kinda it look wired

Comment: I mean "LESS" style sheet which then compile to css not that less